# google web fonts only letters are working

Tags: google-webfonts

I'm trying to use the font 'Cabin Sketch' 
I incluced the font like it says on the google web font page:

html:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin+Sketch:400,700' rel='stylesheet'   type='text/css' >
```

css:

```
body {
font-family: 'Cabin Sketch';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
color: #dbdbdb;
font-size: 14px;
}
```

Letters from a-z are working but any other charakters like .!@ are not working.

In the google web font preview all characters are working.

Other fonts are working perfectly.

I'm using firefox 11.0 and Ubuntu 11.04.

I also created a issue on google font directory:
http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/issues/detail?id=124

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems right, Which browser are you using it with? It should work for all alphabets that it uses. I tested it and it works just fine. Make sure your [browser supports](http://www.webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=@font-face_browser_support) `@font-face`

**jsfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/

**html page**

```
<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin+Sketch:400,700' rel='stylesheet'   type='text/css'/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="font">
        <p>Hey yo</p>
        <p>1234</p>
        <p>! @ .</p>
    </div>
    <div id="normal">
        <p>Hey yo</p>
        <p>1234</p>
        <p>! @ .</p>
    </div>
​</body>​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**css**

```
body {
    padding: 100px;
}
div {
    margin: 10px;
}
#font {
    font-family: 'Cabin Sketch';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
}
​
```

**Preview in Chrome**

[image: preview]

So it is correct, as you see above, it supports non alphabetical characters. Run the fiddle to see yourself. Hope that helps!

Comment: This is working alright on jsfiddle and on a local test page. Any suggestions what can causes this behavior on a bigger project? And I'm using Firefox 11.0.

Comment: Check your inspector to see if any styles are being overridden (for example, what is the style that the inspector sees). Usually the inspector shows the styles from top (high priority overrides everything coming before under it). Easier to use Firebug in Firefox or Web Inspector for Chrome/Safari.

Comment: Ok, of course it was actually my fault. I tested the characters [ and . which are looking pretty similar to a standard font if you are using small font sizes. I used a @ somewhere else on the website which was looking like a default font because in this part I actually used a font that doesn't support these characters but looks similar to 'Cabin Sketch'. I figured it out on a test page when I zoomed in. Thank you very much.